# IIS7 downloading file length

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, content-length

I've following code for file download:

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        context.Response.End();
```

When I run it on my local IIS6 it works fine. Web browser (tested on IE8, Firefox 3.5.2, Opera 10) shows file length before I start download the file.

When I run this code on remote IIS7, web browser doesn't shows file length. File length is unknown.

Why I don't get file length when this code runs under IIS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to check what is actually sent.  My guess is you are getting chunked encoding as a result of buffering being set to false on the IIS7 server.

BTW, drop the Response.End call its quite a traumatic thing to do and is unnecessary (for that matter so is the call to Clear).

**Edit**

Strictly speaking when streaming content with chunked encoding (which is desirable in your scenario) the Content-Length header ought not be present (see [RFC2616 Section 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).)  It seems to me that IIS7 takes it upon itself to enforce this.  In fact I've had a Classic-ASP scenario in which IIS7 throws an error when COM code tries to add a Content-Length header when buffering is off.

This is really annoying because despite what the committee in the ivory towers would like, this header give the end user a very useful piece of info.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting "transfer-encoding: chunked" and Content-Length is not returned. Is any way to get Content-Length in response header? I don't have direct access to IIS7 server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post.... I got it working for IE with the first line.

```
public void WriteCSV(string strData) {
   //Required for IIs7 WS2008R2 fix
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.Clear();


   Response.Buffer = true; 
   Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.csv");
   Response.Write(strData);
   Response.Flush();
   Response.End();
}
```